# Mousemove Chrome Vs Firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, mousemove

I have put together the following code but have noticed a slightly difference in performance when testing it out in both Safari/Chrome and also Firefox.

```
var box = $('#menu');

var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var boxHeight = box.height();
var diff = windowHeight - boxHeight;

var startY = 0;
var dist = 0;
var boxtop = box.position().top;

var boxoffset = box.offset().top;


function movehandler(event){
    box.css('background-color' , '#ffff00');
    dist = (event.pageY - startY);
    var val = boxtop + dist

    box.css('-moz-transform' , 'translate(0px, '+ val +'px)');
    box.css('WebkitTransform' , 'translate(0px, '+ val +'px)');

    if (val < 0) {
        box.css('WebkitTransform' , 'translate(0px, 0px)');
        box.css('-moz-transform' , 'translate(0px, 0px)');

    } else if (val > diff) {
        box.css('WebkitTransform' , 'translate(0px, '+ diff +'px)');
        box.css('-moz-transform' , 'translate(0px, '+ diff +'px)');
    } else {
        box.css('WebkitTransform' , 'translate(0px, '+ val +'px)');
        box.css('-moz-transform' , 'translate(0px, '+ val +'px)');
    };          
}

box.bind('mousedown' , function(event){
    box.css('background-color' , '#ff00ff');
    box.bind('mousemove' , movehandler);
    startY = event.pageY;    
    boxtop = box.position().top;
});

box.bind('mouseup' , function(event){
    box.css('background-color' , '#333');
    boxtop = box.position().top;
    box.unbind('mousemove' , movehandler);
});
```

What I've noticed is that in Chrome/Safari the `#menu` div scrolls smoothly the first and subsequent clicks/moves using the mouse.  BUT in Firefox it works the first click but to get the `#menu` div to move on the 2nd click/move requires you to `mousedown` then `mouseup`before the box moves.  If you try and click and move the div without releasing the mouse, the div seems to float out of the box.

Is there anything in my code which would cause this performance difference, or are both browsers interpreting the mouse events like they should?

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NUnGs/) so you can see what I'm on about.

Also, any general thoughts or comments on my code would be appreicated as I'm always looking to improve.

Comment: sorry, I not found any difference in chrome/firefox(linux) does this solves your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/NUnGs/2/ ?

Comment: sorry but your fiddle just gave a 404 page not found

Comment: sorry, this is correct link http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/NUnGs/3/

Comment: thanks for updating the link.  I can see what you've done, but I can't see the difference. In Chrome I find that when you click the div, the div turns purple, then without letting go of the mouse you can move the mouse (turning the box yellow) and move it up and down WITHOUT letting go of the mouse. Using Firefox however, you click the mouse down, the div turns purple, move the mouse (turns yellow) then let go of the mouse before you can move the div up and down.

Comment: Works for me: FX23 on OSX/Win7

Comment: Ok so turns out that the problem was me, and not running an up to date version of Firefox.  Thanks to @eicto & nmaier for your help and comments